# Hyper-v 2012 - Guest OS not working with a Static IP

Tags: hyper-v, windows-networking

So I have a very strange issue.  I've setup 2 NIC's, 1 for the host OS (windows 2012 with Hyper V) and a guest OS (Windows 2012 - Active Directory).   I've setup 2 physical nics, 1 for the host and another for the VM's.

Unfortunately the problem seems to be when I try to set the guest OS to a static IP on the local subnet (which works with DHCP), but the moment i assign a static IP, it stops communicating with anything but the local IP's for the Host OS.

I've tried several different things for the virtual server (guest OS) and so far nothing is working.  If I leave it set to DHCP, its fine with all connectivity.  However the moment I set it to a static, it stops me.

At the current time I have the Host OS (Server) with 2 physical nic's:

Nic1 - Host OS connectivity
Nic2 - Hyper-v Virtual Switch configured "External network" for all VM's

Guest OS - connects using DHCP through Nic2 (External Network).  Should be bridged, but when I set to static, I lose all connectivity to the external network, but switch back to DHCP and it works great.

Whats going on?  Am I completely missing something obvous here?

Answer (score 1):

So in case anyone finds this question I thought I should at least post the answer I found.

It would appear that the problem is not with my Hyper-V setup.  The problem was with the router that the system was attached to.   I have a ZYXEL USG1000 that is controlling the network with Hyper-V, and it appears that this model does not work in the same way as other router products I've experienced (Cisco/Juniper/etc).

I was able to verify that the VM's could actually ping/access other systems within the same subnet assigned to them, but they still could not cross the gateway.  There is a IP/MAC Binding option within the Zyxel router software and until this VM's MAC was added to the binding list, only then would the gateway pass traffic from the VM's.

So in case anyone else runs into this similar situation, check out your router and the mac/IP binding for your VM's.